# Do custom tags in application.cfc ignore this.customTagPaths?

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

Within my root `application.cfc` I define `this.customTagPaths`.  This is verified to work on all pages, including those in subfolders.  Within one subfolder I have an `application.cfc` that extends this root application.cfc.  Pages within this folder still use the correct custom tags so we know that this is working correctly.

However, when trying to use a custom tag within the `[subfolder]/application.cfc` file itself I believe it is pulling from a different custom tag path.  I added some debug information into the custom tag and it outputs when the custom tag is called from a normal page, but does not output when called from the `application.cfc`.  I do not have access to the server to put debugging information in the other custom tag paths to be sure.

Does code in the `application.cfc` ignore `this.customTagPaths` and, if so, how do I use the specific tag I need?  This custom tag sets a variable in the caller scope, so it cannot be called with a simple `cfInclude`.

**Edit**

I will attempt to address some of the questions in the comments here.

The custom tag in question has been simplified down to this code:

```
    <cfset Caller.groupList = ""> 
    <cfquery name="getGroups">
        SELECT id, name
        FROM groups
        WHERE id = 1
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput query="getGroups">
        <cfset Caller.groupList = #ListAppend(Caller.groupList, name)#> 
    </cfoutput>
    <cfoutput>Caller.groupList: #Caller.groupList#<br></cfoutput>
```

The Application.cfc is using this code:

```
    <cfcomponent extends="RootApplication">
            ............
            <cf_groupList>
            <cfoutput>request.groupList: #request.groupList#<br><br></cfoutput>
    </cfcomponent>
```

When cf_groupList is called directly from a cfm it writes "Call.groupList: xxxx" out to the page and shows the correct values from the dev database.  However, when the Application.cfc runs the custom tag "Call.groupList: xxxx" never appears, but "request.groupList: xxxx" does, and in the latter case it shows the list that we would expect from the live database.  Both the live and dev sites are currently on the same server, which we are in the process of changing, but for now I have no debugging information.

The reason I am calling a custom tag from Application.cfc is because this tag is used many other places.  Simply copying and pasting the code into Application.cfc would solve the problem, but then we have an issue of duplicated code that we need to remember to update in two places in the future.  Using the custom tag in the application.cfc instead of duplicating code seemed like the correct approach.

Mark, you are correct.  When placed in the parent Application.cfc the custom tag works correctly.  In the child it does not.

Comment: What does the custom tag do? How are you calling it? How are you extending the Application.cfc in the parent folder? Share some code.

Comment: About this access to the server stuff, are you saying that you are not able to enable debugging information on the machine where you develop and test?

Comment: As a follow-up to Dan's question, you should have a copy of this code running locally, or at least on a remote server that is NOT your production server to make sure you can test and debug issues. If you are not doing that, you need to start.

Comment: Instead of describing your situation, as Scott says: give us code. Pare down your situation into a repro case and post it. In the process of doing this, you'll quite likely solve your own problem. But it should not be up to us to guess the details of your code. Plus it's an unhelpful approach to solving your problem. You can at least answer your *headline* question in about 5min of coding. From there... you can finetune your code & your question.

Comment: If I understand you are saying a custom tag call using this.customTagPaths works in the parent Application.cfc (that's right isn't it? you've tested it in parent?) but not in a child applicaiton.cfc. In addition, using the defined custom tag path OUTSIDE the child application.cfc works correctly. It is only WITHIN the child application.cfc that it does not work. Do I have this right?

Comment: I would add that I would have to think pretty hard of a reason to use a custom tag inside an application.cfc at all. Typically they are useful for display functionality - everything else can go into components.

Comment: Question updated to address questions in the comments.  Thanks.